# Express.js randomly logs out

Tags: node.js, express

EDIT: I still don't know what the problem is, but I've isolated this to a Firefox problem.

I hesitate in asking this question because I can't isolate any code that caused it. I have an Express.js app that logs in with 0Auth, then redirects to some endpoint. After it loads the html, it might randomly sign out. I didn't tell it to sign out, and I can't find anything in my code that would cause this behavior. I have even tried changing all instances of `/auth/login` to `/auth/exit`, but I still see the `GET /auth/logout` in the npm console. Stack trace says the caller is `node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js`, which is unhelpful. I can use a `console.log` to show that the sign in was successful. I can see the token in my request. As far as I know, authentication errors in my code goes through a single middleware, and a `console.log` shows that it never passes through there. That means something is redirecting to the logout endpoint and I can't find out what. The problem comes and goes, it works sometimes as magically as it doesn't work. I can start the local server, then log in a bunch of times and it will keep logging me out. Then, it will function correctly for some time, and repeat the cycle, with nothing changed.

[image: npm console output]

I'm at wit's end. Has anyone experienced such an issue, where Express automatically logs out sometimes, or can give suggestions on what to try?

Comment: Are you using a middleware called morgan

Comment: I see that in my package.json, yes, 'morgan ~1.9.0'.

Comment: try searching `require('morgan')` in you codebase

Comment: Okay, yeah, I see it in app.js. It is used once with the line `app.use(logger('dev'));`.

Comment: Simply remove it if you don't want logging

Comment: Oh, I see. There might be miscommunication. It's not the logging I don't want, but Express redirects to the `/auth/logout` endpoint, which contains the function I think passport sets up to clear the session. I don't have any code that I know of that causes Express to redirect to `/auth/logout` after rendering `/customer_orders`, as shown in the picture. I don't want Express to redirect to that endpoint.